# How can I run google cloud authentication credentials from an npm script

Tags: node.js, google-vision

I'm trying to build a simple app that makes use of the google cloud vision api for image analysis using node, though can't workout how to build the auth step into a simple npm script.

To access my account I currently set my auth credentials in the terminal (a bash terminal though I'm on a windows pc) as below, and can then run my server.js file which calls the google api.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\tim\01_animal_snap\my-key.json"`

This clearly doesn't take that long to write out and works fine, but I'd love to simply run a command like `npm run auth` instead.

I tried putting the following into my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "auth": "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=\"C:\\Users\\tim\\01_animal_snap\\my-key.json\"",
```

But when I run the script I get the following error:

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I thought this might be an issue with running the 'export' command in a bash environment on windows (maybe npm scrips get executed in cmd or powershell by default?) and so installed cross-env and changed my script to:

```
"scripts": {
    "auth": "cross-env export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=\"C:\\Users\\tim\\01_animal_snap\\my-key.json\"",
```

Though I'm still getting the same error about export not being recognised. How can I run this command using an npm script?

Comment: I think I have written this script that you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-credentials-helper please let me know if that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

export is not required when cros-env is used.

Try with

```
"auth": "cross-env  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="c://..."
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and don't get an error when I run the auth command, but running my npm start command immediately afterwards ("start": "nodemon server.js") gives me the below error which indicates I'm not authenticated:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials.....
```

So the auth script still isn't executing

Comment: that is another error. Your first error was related to cross-env. Create a new question or research about your new error.